# Optimize Visualforce Page for Salesforce1

Tags: layout, styles, salesforce, visualforce, force.com

I created a simple visualforce page to override the standard salesforce.com page for "New" and "Edit" for a Custom Object.
It is pretty simple, it was just because in the standard salesforce.com page the textarea was not wide enough, since the form is splitted in two columns. (Or am I wrong? Is there a way to accomplish that without creating a custom visualforce page?)
Well, here is the code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Object__c">
<apex:sectionHeader title="Object Edit" subtitle="{!if(Object__c.id==null,'New Object',Object__c.Name)}"/>
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Object Edit" mode="edit">
        <apex:pageblockbuttons >
             <apex:commandbutton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
             <apex:commandbutton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
         </apex:pageblockbuttons>
         <apex:pagemessages />
         <apex:pageblockSection title="Basics" columns="2">
             <apex:inputField value="{!Object__c.Field1__c}"/>
             ... more fields
         </apex:pageblockSection>
         <apex:pageblocksection title="Details" columns="1">
             <apex:inputField value="{!Object__c.Field10__c}"/>
             ... more fields
         </apex:pageblocksection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Ok, the page looks good on force.com, but when I open it from within the salesforce1-App on my iPad it has the same style like on force.com and not the nice styling like the other (standard salesforce.com page-)forms in the salesforce1-App?

Answer (score 0):

To get the styling right, consider using the Mobile Design Templates: https://developer.salesforce.com/en/mobile/services/mobile-templates/templates-faq.

I think you would also benefit from reviewing this slide deck: http://www.slideshare.net/developerforce/visualforce-in-salesforce1-1-1. It specifically asks developers to avoid using pageBlocks in Salesforce1. The author of those slides is Sandeep Bhanot, who, in general, is a great person to connect to on Twitter/Youtube, etc, for all your Salesforce1 needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can have textarea span 2 columns in std page layout by putting it to separate section and setting columns to 1. Just hover over the section header, click the wrench icon on the right and you should get a popup like this:

[image]

I'd say for such change it's bit of an overkill to go full VF page route. But if you really need it or my trick won't work - there are few questions on Salesforce-dedicated site that might be a good start for you:

- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22290/sfdc-styleguide-usage-questions-in-salesforce1
- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25541/salesforce1-look-feel-in-visualforce
- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/27788/how-to-do-visualforce-page-with-the-same-look-feel-as-salesforce1
- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/37111/mobile-view-one-one-app-differs-from-native-salesforce1-view (not really related but it's my answer so :P Seriously though - the presentations I've linked to in that answer really helped me to kick off my development)